# error message "system is out of GPU and shared host memory" during rendering

Tags: rendering

i am rendering animation with gpu. but when rendering between frame 1 and 2, there is an error message saying "system is out of GPU and shared host memory"

how to solve this error

[image: e=Error Message]

(Render Cycles)
(Blender 2.91.2)

Comment: The error message tells us that your graphics card is out of memory. Either switch to CPU, try to optimize your scene *or* try another card with more RAM if you'd like to render the scene as is.